# how can I get no more than three n-grams

Tags: python-3.x

I am finding the n-grams using the following function.

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

booksAfterRemovingStopWords = ['Zombies and Calculus by Colin Adams', 'Zone to Win: Organizing to Compete in an Age of Disruption', 'Zig Zag: The Surprising Path to Greater Creativity']
booksWithNGrams = list()

for line_no, line in enumerate(booksAfterRemovingStopWords):
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    output = list(ngrams(tokens, 3))
    temp = list()
    for x in output:  # Adding n-grams
        temp.append(' '.join(x))
    booksWithNGrams.append(temp)

print(booksWithNGrams)
```

The output looks like:

```
[['Zombies and Calculus', 'and Calculus by', 'Calculus by Colin', 'by Colin Adams'], ['Zone to Win:', 'to Win: Organizing', 'Win: Organizing to', 'Organizing to Compete', 'to Compete in', 'Compete in an', 'in an Age', 'an Age of', 'Age of Disruption'], ['Zig Zag: The', 'Zag: The Surprising', 'The Surprising Path', 'Surprising Path to', 'Path to Greater', 'to Greater Creativity']]
```

However, I want no more that three n-grams. I mean I want the output to be like:

```
[['Zombies and Calculus', 'and Calculus by', 'Calculus by Colin'], ['Zone to Win:', 'to Win: Organizing', 'Win: Organizing to'], ['Zig Zag: The', 'Zag: The Surprising', 'The Surprising Path']]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd do it:

Logic:
Just count till three in the loop and break on `i>2` (counts i=0,1,2 and breaks).

```py
booksAfterRemovingStopWords = ['Zombies and Calculus by Colin Adams', 'Zone to Win: Organizing to Compete in an Age of Disruption', 'Zig Zag: The Surprising Path to Greater Creativity']
booksWithNGrams = list()
        
for line_no, line in enumerate(booksAfterRemovingStopWords):
    tokens = line.split(" ")
    output = list(ngrams(tokens, 3))
    temp = list()
    for i,x in enumerate(output):# Adding n-grams
        if i>2:
            break
        temp.append(' '.join(x))
    booksWithNGrams.append(temp)
```